# How do I use the ratio test to determine convergence or divergence in this problem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, absolute-convergence

I have the problem:

$$a_{n} = \frac{e^{n+5}}{\sqrt{n+7}(n+3)!}$$

I am told to use the ratio test to determine convergence or divergence (or the test could be inconclusive).

So I take the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}\frac{1}{a_{n}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{e^{n+6}}{\sqrt{n+8}(n+4)n!} \frac{\sqrt{n+7}(n+3)n!}{e^{n+5}}$$
$$= (\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{e^{n+6}}{e^{n+5}}) (\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+7}}{\sqrt{n+8}}) (\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+3}{n+4})$$

I reorganized and canceled the ***n!*** terms.

I keep getting:
$$(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{e^{n+6}}{e^{n+5}}) = e$$
$$(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+7}}{\sqrt{n+8}}) = 1$$
$$(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+3}{n+4}) = 1$$

So my limit is ***e***, which indicates the series diverges. However, according both to MathWorks and WolframAlpha this is incorrect. The limit is actually 0, indicating the series converges.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You replaced $(n+k)!$ with $(n+k)\cdot n!$, that's incorrect. We have $\frac{(n+3)!}{(n+4)!} = \frac{1}{n+4}$.

Comment: There's a mistake when you work with $(n+3)!$ and $(n+4)!$. So the last limit should be $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n+4}$. And that gives you the result: $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake writing the ratio. It should be
$$
\frac{e^{n+6}}{\sqrt{n+8}(n+4)!} \frac{\sqrt{n+7}(n+3)!}{e^{n+5}}
=
\frac{e\cdot e^{n+5}}{\sqrt{n+8}(n+4)(n+3)!} \frac{\sqrt{n+7}(n+3)!}{e^{n+5}}
$$
not
$$\frac{e^{n+6}}{\sqrt{n+8}(n+4)n!} \frac{\sqrt{n+7}(n+3)n!}{e^{n+5}}.$$

The mistake is in that you wrote $(n+k)! = (n+k)n!$, which is **not** true.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{n+6}}{(n+4)!\sqrt{n+8}}}{\dfrac{e^{n+5}}{(n+3)!\sqrt{n+7}}}=\dfrac{e\sqrt{n+7}}{(n+4)\sqrt{n+8}}\underbrace{\to}_{n\to \infty} 0.$$